# Recursion for inductive process

Tags: r, recursion

I am self-learning R, and I am struggling with code finding stopping time (kns, ks) of an arbitrary stochastic process which can be defined as following:

**Basis**: k0= inf {u >=0: max_[0,u]- min_[0,u]=H }

if X(k0)= max_[0,k0]X, then k0s = inf { u in [0,k0]: X(u)= min_[0,k0]X }

if X(k0)= min_[0,k0]X, then k0s = inf { u in [0,k0]: X(u)= max_[0,k0]}X }

**Step n to n+1**:

- if $X(kn)-X(ksn)=H, then:

  k(n+1)= inf {t >= kn : max_[kn,t]}X-X(t) =H }

  ks(n+1)= inf { t in [kn, k(n+1)]: X(t)=max_[kn, k(n+1)]X }
- if X(kn)-X(ksn)=-H, then:

  k(n+1)= inf {t >= n : X(t)-min{[kn,t]X =H }

  k(n+1)= inf { t in [kn, k(n+1)]: X(t)=min_[kn, k(n+1)]X }

My following code is able to find the basis (k0s,ks) and next two pair (ks1,k1), (ks2,k2).

```
    step<-function(v){
     z=numeric(300)
     for(i in 1:300){z[i]=max(v[1:i])-min(v[1:i])}
     k0<-min(which(z>=0.0005))
     k0s<-if (v[k0]==max(v[1:k0])) min(which(v==min(v[1:k0]))) else if (v[k0]==min(v[1:k0])) min(which(v==max(v[1:k0])))
     x=numeric(300)
     if (v[k0]-v[k0s]>=0.0005) {
     for (i in k0:300){x[i]=max(v[k0:i])-v[i]}
     k1<-min(which(x>=0.0005))
     k1s<-min(which(v==max(v[k0:k1])))
     }
     if (v[k0]-v[k0s]<=-0.0005) {
     for (i in k0:300) {x[i]=-min(v[k0:i])+v[i]}
     k1<-min(which(x>=0.0005))
     k1s<-min(which(v==min(v[k0:k1])))
     }
     y=numeric(300)
     if (v[k1]-v[k1s]>=0.0005) {
     for (i in k1:300){y[i]=max(v[k1:i])-v[i]}
     k2<-min(which(y>=0.0005))
     k2s<-min(which(v==max(v[k1:k2])))
     }
     if (v[k1]-v[k1s]<=-0.0005) {
     for (i in k1:300) {y[i]=-min(v[k1:i])+v[i]}
     k2<-min(which(y>=0.0005))
     k2s<-min(which(v==min(v[k1:k2])))
      }
     return(c(k0s,k0,k1s,k1,k2s,k2))
     }
```

v here is a vector and I used:

```
     v<-rnorm(300)
```

to test my code.

However, I would like to generalise my code to find (ksn,kn) ( not only the for first three stopping time of the whole process). Since the way to find (kns, ks) depends on {k(n-1)s, k(n-1)}, I am thinking of writing a recursive function; but I have problem with the loop in my code and don't know how transform it into recursion. Can anyone please suggest/ point me to some source that I can improve my code??

Since English is not my first language, please excuse any typing mistakes.

Thank you so much in advance and I really appreciate any help.

Comment: LaTeX syntax is not supported on SO. Please fix your question's formatting. However, *in general*, R is not good at recursion. It's better to use loops. However at a first glance it looks like you could use `cummin` and `cummax` instead of those `for` loops.